# Call to xmlhttprequest from page onload event is not working OK when Back from another page

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onload

After going from my page to anther page by pressing a link, and than back to current page, than in call to xmlhttprequest from onload event, The js code of xhr.open and xhr.send is working, but the sever side code called by xhr is not running, and in xhr.onreadystatechange function the xhr.responseText is returning his old value.

In this scenario off comming back from another page, call to xmlhttprequest from document.onreadystatechange event is also not working OK.

The same code works OK when I call it from onload in the first page loading (before going to another page and returning), or when I call it from a button click.

Why the call to xmlhttprequest from onload event is not working OK when Back from another page?

I'm using Chrome.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallAJAX() {
    xhr = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = AJAX_onreadystatechange;
    xhr.open("GET", '/MyPage.aspx', true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
function AJAX_onreadystatechange() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert('xhr.responseText=' + xhr.responseText);
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    //alert is working also after going to link and than back to current page
    alert('alert')
    //Call to xmlhttprequest from page onload event - is Not working OK - after going to link and than back to current page
    CallAJAX();
}
</script>
<!--here is the "link" mentioned in the above comment-->
<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
<!--Call to xmlhttprequest from button onclick event - is working OK-->
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallAJAX();" />
```

**Update**

I found the problem:

In some browsers, and in some circumstances, xhr brought the xhr.responseText
value from browser cache, instead to call server.

Here is the solution:

This problem solved by adding unique query string param to url param of xhr.open. This guaranty that the ajax will avoid using the cache, and always hit the server, because with the unique param, the url is turned to unique in every call to xhr.open.

The unique value is produced by "new Date().getTime()" which returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and now.

This is the solution code:

```
    xhr.open("GET", '/MyPage.aspx?uniqueParamVal=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

Comment: you should post your code...

Comment: Try to use : `setTimeout(functionWhoThatUseXmlhttprequest(), 0)`

Comment: In GChrome, open Dev tool (F12), switch to `Network` tab, Click "Filter" icon -> select `XHR`. Then, reload page and inspect your request for viewing what client send to the server and what the server respond to client.

Comment: i added my code above, and make the question more accurate. thanx Pascal Le Merrer.

Comment: setTimeout not solved the issue. thanx R3tep

Comment: thanx Reegan for your response. i used the Chrome Dev tool filter on the XHR, and in column "Size Content", the value is "(from cache)", when the normal value should be something like "558B".

Comment: i made a workaround to the issue by using next code:  

window.onload = function () {  
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", MyEventHandler_handleMouseMove, false);  
}  
function MyEventHandler_handleMouseMove(oEvent) {  
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", MyEventHandler_handleMouseMove, false);  
    CallAJAX();  
}  

but this is not a perfect solution...

Comment: update - setTimeout work OK in the above code.
but this is short code i made for this thread, and my real code is more complicated (i can't copy it to here), and there i couldn't make it work. thanx again R3tep

Comment: I added Update answer an solution to my post above, which i came to by the tip off Reegan. Thanx you all.